# Any way to review my account information on computer instead of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, accounts

I setup a lot of iPhones at work for our clients. For every phone I setup, I create the Apple ID and install a bunch of apps we use on site. Every time I go to install the first app I have to punch in the password, then get a popup "This Apple ID has not yet been used in the iTunes Store" and have to go through and fill out the location information, then enter the password again before I can start installing apps.

Our default passwords are long, so typing them in multiple times is annoying, and our address information is also difficult to type on the phone keyboard. I'm hoping there's some way I can do more of this process on a computer instead of the phone itself. I tried signing into the Apple ID on the website and filling in the "Shipping Address" there but the phone still asked me to review and I had to fill it all out again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you get a USB hub or Keyboard so you can type effectively on the iPhone and then re-examine your process.

---

If you set up too many Apple ID from one device, you could get locked on the Apple side (in the past the trigger was often around 50+ accounts created and faster banning if you used the same Apple ID for installing apps on multiple devices). It a painful process in the days of the initial iPad release as the blocks would come and go (presumably there was a time based algorithm that would trigger and reset) and most of the iPads were WiFi only. Once it was clear how we were getting banned, we had to ask for an IP address exception from their anti-fraud systems. This happened via Apple Sales engineers a few times since they had no process back then to make institutional accounts like you need.

- https://appleid.apple.com/account

I see no limits or asterisks like in the past saying you only get 5 ID per device, so maybe start slowly and make sure you have purchase information and an Apple Sales person contact info handy just in case.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/108647

Hopefully you can do more of the setup from a device with a keyboard and copy / paste if that part of the password security process you have. My experience is you will always have to review the sign in on each new device - the only exception might be if you create institutional Apple ID in bulk by uploading a spreadsheet and using the Apple Business Manager and device enrollment infrastructure. Then you don’t even need to touch the phones or take them out of the box to assign them to the account you created.

---

Absolutely pursue a chat with Apple or your sales partner (clearly you’re buying items in volume). There are far better options now with MDM, directory integration and bulk account creation tools. Those saved us months of effort over the past few years. No more IP banning, no more requests to be unblocked, we are happy to use the tools Apple set up for this (and those tools unlock other efficiencies and capabilities you can’t get with the DIY account creation process).

- https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-business-manager/sign-up-axm402206497/web

Comment: Our office internet appears to be blocked from creating new accounts. The site stopped working on the computer around November for our whole team, so now we have to create the accounts on the phone over LTE. This happened last year around the same time too, so we thought maybe there's a max quantity per year. I'm a bit disappointed/worried that we're still stuck because I thought it "reset" after New Years last time.

Comment: Aah - you know you’ve been IP banned. Well, contact Apple or expect to use a physical keyboard until you’re ready for a path they want institutional account creation to follow. I’ve found their engineers to be very understanding and easy to arrange a meeting when you approach them through your sales channel.